# Cannot turn off Hibernate's debug logs

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j, log4j2

I cannot use log4j2 or logback such that the log4j2.xml or properties files can not work on it.

```
09:48:33.279 [main] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider
09:48:33.355 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator].
09:48:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.secure.spi.JaccIntegrator].
09:48:33.387 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl - Adding Integrator [org.hibernate.cache.internal.CollectionCacheInvalidator].
09:48:33.475 [main] INFO org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.12.Final
09:48:33.479 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are not allowed to use log4j or logback? Or that you don't know how to configure loggers to turn off Hibernate logging?

Comment: yeah , it is logback. I have finished it by creating logback.xml in resources folder. But I don't know why the log4j cannot work.

Comment: Hibernate uses JBoss Logging as logging API: check [their documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/logging/Logging.html) to learn how to bind it to a concrete logging backend.